# URL Rewrite from path to .html

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, path

I've this URL:

http://www.domain.com/search/madonna

and this condition runs properly:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)?$ /index.php?s=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want to use this URL:

http://www.domain.com/search/madonna.html

But this condition doesn't work and I get a 404 error:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)\.html$ index.php?s=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you using both rules at the same time?

Comment: yes but I've remove the firs rule and doesn't work  :-(